# Add bookmarks to Safari using Perl?

Tags: perl, safari, bookmarks

Is there a way to programmatically add bookmarks to Safari using Perl?

I would prefer a solution that works even if Safari is running, but of course—if there is no other way—I would also settle for a solution that requires closing the application first. If it helps, I'm running in OS X.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else is looking for a solution. I've eventually managed to do this by directly editing Safari's bookmarks file (Located in something like `~/Libary/Safari/Bookmarks.plist`). In order to read, modify and update the `plist` using perl I went for the OSX Foundation module ([this article might be helpful](http://macdevcenter.com/pub/a/mac/2005/07/29/plist.html?page=1)).